# Page Cache and i18n on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I have an application where I use i18n and Globalize3 for models translations. Im implementing page cache right now and wanna know how do you handle page cache with i18n on ruby on rails?

Answer (score 4):

If you stick with the rule: **one url = one page**, caching is easy.

So easy I don't really know what I could add... just fragment-cache or page-cache.

If you don't have the locale in your url (which is not a good practice), caching would be far more difficult.

[from the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html):

> You may be tempted to store the chosen locale in a session or a
>   cookie. Do not do so. The locale should be transparent and a part of
>   the URL. This way you don’t break people’s basic assumptions about the
>   web itself: if you send a URL of some page to a friend, she should see
>   the same page, same content. A fancy word for this would be that
>   you’re being RESTful. Read more about the RESTful approach in Stefan
>   Tilkov’s articles. There may be some exceptions to this rule, which
>   are discussed below.

Comment: it might be in the URL once but does it need to be in the url on every request?

Comment: definitely yes. The rule is: when you send an url to someone, he should see the same thing that you see (except when auth is at stakes)

Comment: Homepages of sites like Facebook and Twitter don't seem to have the locale in the URL.. how are they doing it?

Comment: @samvermette: they use the language sent by the browser: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE

Comment: @apneadiving yes, but the URL is always the same (twitter.com, for instance). So I'm wondering: how are they doing caching if one url != one page?

Comment: @samvermette: they won't do any page caching, would be non sense for real time wall/tweets.I guess there is much fragment caching/query caching though.

Comment: @apneadiving haha good call, hadn't even thought about that. Thanks!